# How to find all solutions of the following system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

**Problem.** Let $m, n$ be natural numbers. Can we find all the solutions of the following system of equations?
$$\sum_{1\leq i\leq m, 1\leq j \leq  n} x_{ij} =1\\
\left(  \sum_{1\leq p\leq m} x_{pj}  \right) \left(  \sum_{1\leq q\leq n} x_{iq}    \right) = x_{ij}
\hspace{0.5cm} 
\forall 1\leq i\leq m, 1\leq j \leq  n$$

**Note.** The problem has many solutions. Indeed, consider the simple case $m=n=2$, it is easy to see that
$$x_{ij}=\frac{1}{4} \hspace{0.5cm}  \forall i,j\in \{1,2\}$$
and $$x'_{1j}=\frac{1}{2}; x'_{2j}=0 \hspace{0.5cm}  \forall j\in \{1,2\}$$ are solutions.

**Comment.** I have no idea how to tackle above problem. So I really appreciate any hints!

Comment: The use of $i,j$ both within the summations as bound variables and on the right hand side as unbound subscripts is slightly confusing.  On the face of it, you have $mn+1$ equations in $mn$ unknowns, so if there are solutions, presumably this indicates some redundancy in the equations.  Perhaps reformulating the problem in terms of row sums and column sums (marginal sums) would help ferret out that redundancy.

Comment: Oh many thanks for your suggestion about the indices $i,j$. I corrected it. Regarding the use of marginal sums, I have tried, but nothing progresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformulating the problem in terms of row sums:

$$ r_i = \sum_{1\le q \le n} x_{iq} $$

and column sums:

$$ s_j = \sum_{1\le p \le m} x_{pj} $$

gives a full set of solutions rather quickly.

The sum of all entries $x_{ij}$ being one, the first requirement, implies both the sum of all row sums equals one and the sum of all column sums equals one:

$$ \sum_{1\le i \le m} r_i = 1 $$

$$ \sum_{1\le j \le n} s_j = 1 $$

So these two conditions are *necessary* for a solution.  The final requirement is just that:

$$ s_j r_i = x_{ij} $$

which is satisfied by assigning that value to $x_{ij}$ once the $r_i,s_j$ values are chosen.

It remains only to show that the conditions above for $r_i,s_j$ are *sufficient*.  That is, given the definition $x_{ij} = r_i s_j$, we check the row sums and column sums are as we supposed them to be:

$$ \sum_{1\le q \le n} x_{iq} = \sum_{1\le q \le n} r_i s_q = r_i \sum_{1\le q \le n} s_q = r_i $$

$$ \sum_{1\le p \le m} x_{pj} = \sum_{1\le p \le m} r_p s_j = s_j \sum_{1\le p \le m} r_p = s_j $$

Note that we've used respectively here that the sum of column sums $s_q$ is one and that the sum of row sums $r_p$ is one.

To summarize, any choice of such values $r_i,s_j$ for $1\le i \le m$ and $1\le j \le n$ gives a solution of the original problem.  Conversely, any solution will be of that form.

Comment: Yes this is indeed the solution that I am looking for! Thank you so much for your amazing answer!